# How to change div content in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql

I want to change the div's id intFrom. Content after inserting data to the database, I want the code not just echo **¡Enhorabuena**!...

But replace the form with **¡Enhorabuena**! I maybe, I could replace the form using AJAX.

**Here is the code:**
**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action=""> 
    <div>
    <select value="genero" name="genderselect" id="genero" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">
    <option value="none"  selected>- Selecciona Género - </option>
    <option value="Mujer">Mujer</option>
    <option value="Hombre">Hombre</option>
    </select>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" placeholder="Nombre completo" required="required" autofocus="autofocus" />
    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Correo electrónico" required="required" />  
    </div>
    <div>
    <div class="infForm img">
    <img src="http://www.miraqueguapa.com/Landings/General/img/biotherm.png" alt="Imagen Crema Aquasource Biotherm" class="biotherm">
    </div>
    <div class="infForm text">
    <div class="legal">
    <input type="checkbox" id="cblegales" value="1" name="cblegales" required="required" autofocus="autofocus">  
    <p>He leído y acepto la <a class="enlace_pp" href="http://www.miraqueguapa.com/content/5-privacidad-proteccion-datos" target="_blank">política de privacidad</a></p>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR DATOS" name="submit_form" style="    background-color: #DF2848;border: none;border-radius: 0px;color: white;width: 200px;float: right;padding-left: 50px;cursor: pointer;margin-top: -5px;" />
</div>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

**PHP**

```
 <?php
  if (isset($_POST['submit_form'])) {
                        include 'connection.php';

                        $name=$_POST["name"];
                        $email=$_POST["email"];
                        $gender=$_POST["genderselect"];

                        if($gender=="none"){
                            echo"</br>";
                            echo"por favor selecciona nuestro género";
                            $link = null;
                        }
                        else{

                            $i=0;
                            $statement = $link->prepare("select email from webform where email = :email");
                            $statement->execute(array(':email' => "$email"));
                            $row = $statement->fetchAll();
                            foreach($row as $key) {
                                $i=$i+1;
                            }
                            if ($i !=0) {
                                echo" Este correo electrónico ya está registrado";
                                $link = null;
                            }
                            else{

                                $statement = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO webform(name, email, gender)
                                VALUES(:name, :email, :gender)");
                                $statement->execute(array(
                                    "name" => "$name",
                                    "email" => "$email",
                                    "gender" => "$gender"
                                ));
                                $link = null;

                                echo"¡Enhorabuena!"."<br/>";
                                echo"Tus datos se han enviado correctamente. A partir de ahora recibirás cada semana las últimas novedades y las mejores ofertas en Cosmética de las marcas más prestigiosas del mercado.";

                            }}}
                    ?>
```

Comment: What is your question regarding this code?

Comment: how can I replace the form with ¡Enhorabuena! text after the code submits

Answer (score 0):

You need to add simple `if else` statement.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit_form'])) {
  // Your code after form get submitted.
}
else {
  // Show default form.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just load your HMTL Code in to your PHP as a kind of "Template" with `file_get_contents(__DIR__ . "Path/To/Your.html");` in to a variable and do a simple `str_replace('id="your_element_id"', 'id="replace_id"', $template_variable);` and echo your Template after if you just want to replace an ID.

If you want to change something within the Form, do it as i said above with `str_replace('tag_you_are_looking_for', 'should_be_replaced_with', $template_variable);`